# How to check if a date is in a list of dates - TSQL

Tags: t-sql, date

I am trying to create a SQL query that checks if a date is in a list of dates but my query doesn't work...

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE field1 = value1
  AND convert(nvarchar(15),date_start,101) IN 
    (SELECT convert(nvarchar(15),date_end,101) 
             FROM TABLE2
         )
```

This query should return some values but it doesn't...

Comment: What doesn't work? Can you post examples of input, actual and expected output?

Comment: Ok, my fault... there was a missing date in one of the tables. I populate it and the query works fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do not convert the data i think there  is no need for this

Try this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE field1 = value1
  AND date_start IN 
    (SELECT date_end FROM TABLE2)
```